# Import csv file into psql db

Tags: postgresql, csv, delimiter

I want to import csv file to psql db...

I have searched and tried using copy, also referred https://www.commandprompt.com/ppbook/r23528 and the syntax i used is:

```
copy location from 'file.csv' with delimiters '\t' NULL as 'NULL' CSV;
```

Note : My csv file is delimited by 'tab' .

After executing the above cmd 1st time, it shows :

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near ""\t""
LINE 1: ...om 'file.csv' using delimiters "\t" ;
```

and for 2nd time,

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "copy"
LINE 2: copy location from 'file.csv' using d...
```

**After Editing,**

2nd time i tried to use like ,

```
copy location from 'file.csv' with delimiter E'\t' NULL as 'NULL' CSV;

ERROR: extra data after last expected column 
CONTEXT: COPY location, line 1: "AD AD100   Canillo  42.5833    1.6667  6"
```

My table description is

```
Table "public.location"

 Column    |          Type          | Modifiers 
-------------+------------------------+-----------
 countrycode | character varying(2)   | 
 postalcode  | character varying(20)  | 
 place       | character varying(100) | 
 state       | character varying(20)  | 
 country     | character varying(100) | 
 country2    | character varying(20)  | 
 community   | character varying(100) | 
 community2  | character varying(20)  | 
 latitude    | double precision       | 
 longitude   | double precision       | 
 accuracy    | integer                |
```

how to solve this?

**Input:**

```
AD      AD100   Canillo                                                 42.5833 1.6667  6
AD      AD200   Encamp                                                  42.5333 1.6333  6
AD      AD300   Ordino                                                  42.6    1.55    6
AD      AD400   La Massana                                                      42.5667 1.4833  6
AD      AD500   Andorra la Vella                                                        42.5    1.5     6
AD      AD600   Sant Julià de Lòria                                                     42.4667 1.5     6
AD      AD700   Escaldes-Engordany                                                      42.5    1.5667  6
AR      3636    "POZO CERCADO (EL CHORRO (F), DPTO. RIVADAVIA (S))"     SALTA   A                                       -23.4933        -61.9267        3
AR      4123    LAS SALADAS     SALTA   A                                       -25.7833        -64.5   4
AR      4126    LA MARAVILLA    SALTA   A                                       -26.0833        -65.263 3
AR      4126    TALA    SALTA   A                                       -26.1167        -65.2833        4
AR      4126    LA ASUNCION     SALTA   A                                       -26.0833        -65.263 3
AR      4126    BRETE   SALTA   A                                       -26.0667        -65.3667        4
AR      4126    EL SUNCHAL      SALTA   A                                       -26.0833        -65.263 3
AR      4126    CEIBAL  SALTA   A                                       -26.1   -65.0167        4
AR      4126    BARADERO        SALTA   A                                       -26.0833        -65.263 3
AR      4126    CANDELARIA      SALTA   A                                       -26.1   -65.1   4
AR      4126    ALEM    SALTA   A                                       -26.0833        -65.263 3
AR      4126    EL BRETE        SALTA   A                                       -26.0667        -65.3667        4
AR      4126    EL CUIBAL       SALTA   A                                       -26.0833        -65.263 3
AR      4126    EL JARDIN       SALTA   A                                       -26.0833        -65.3833        4
AR      4126    OVEJERO SALTA   A                                       -26.0833        -65.263 3
AR      4126    LOS MOGOTES     SALTA   A                                       -26.0333        -65.2   4
AR      4126    "MIRAFLORES (TALA, DPTO. CANDELARIA)"   SALTA   A                                       -26.0833        -65.263 3
```

This is some eg for input...

when i open this file in ms xcel sheet, with delimiter tab , it seperates the data correctly to the relevent coloumn..

**input files with tab and null values,**

```
AD\tAD100\tCanillo\t\n\t\n\t\n\t\n\t\n\t\n\t42.5833\t1.6667\t6
AD\tAD200\tEncamp\t\n\t\n\t\n\t\n\t\n\t\n\t42.5333\t1.6333\t6
AR\t3636\t"POZO CERCADO (EL CHORRO (F), DPTO. RIVADAVIA (S))"\tSALTA\tA\t\n\t\n\t\n\t\n\t-23.4933\t-61.9267\t3
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Per documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-copy.html) on the `COPY` statement, it should be `WITH DELIMITER` and not *DELIMITERS*.

Also, `COPY` syntax had changed and you're encouraged to use the following:

```
COPY location FROM 'file.csv' WITH (FORMAT csv, DELIMITER '\t',  NULL 'NULL');
```

---

**EDIT:**

I've used the supplied information to test how `COPY` will work on the presented data:

```
CREATE TABLE atest (
    countrycode text CHECK (length(countrycode) <= 2),
    postalcode  text CHECK (length(postalcode) <=20), 
    place       text CHECK (length(place) <= 100), 
    state       text CHECK (length(state) <= 20), 
    country     text CHECK (length(country) <= 100), 
    country2    text CHECK (length(country2) <= 20), 
    community   text CHECK (length(community) <= 100), 
    community2  text CHECK (length(community2) <= 20),
    latitude    double precision,
    longitude   double precision,
    accuracy    integer);
```

I've used the above mentioned command (adopted a bit):

```
COPY atest FROM '/Users/viy/atest2.csv'
     WITH (FORMAT csv, DELIMITER E'\t',  NULL '\n');
```

And got the same error as described above. This is expected, 'cos there're too many empty fields. Let's look at the `CSV` data and how it matches table definition (all `\t` replaced with new lines):

```
AD       countrycode
AD100    postalcode
Canillo  place
\n       state
\n       country
\n       country2
\n       community
\n       community2
\n       latitude
42.5833  longitude
1.6667   accuracy
6        <-- this one gives the error!
```

So, in order to get data loaded you have to review your source data and remove an extra empty field in the middle. Another way is to adjust table's definition to match you source data.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this might be useful for postgres 9.1.4 ,
I am using postgres 8.3 , as you said i changed my syntax as 

copy location from 'file.csv' with delimiter E'\t' NULL as 'NULL' CSV;

ERROR:  extra data after last expected column
CONTEXT:  COPY location, line 1: "AD AD100 Canillo       42.5833 1.6667 6"

how to solve this?

Comment: @SangeethaNarayanaMoorthy, please, include definition of your table into the post (use psql's `\d+ <table_name> command).

Comment: Column    |          Type          | Modifiers 
-------------+------------------------+-----------
 countrycode | character varying(2)   | 
 postalcode  | character varying(20)  | 
 place       | character varying(100) | 
 state       | character varying(20)  | 
 country     | character varying(100) | 
 country2    | character varying(20)  | 
 community   | character varying(100) | 
 community2  | character varying(20)  | 
 latitude    | double precision       | 
 longitude   | double precision       | 
 accuracy    | integer                |

Comment: @SangeethaNarayanaMoorthy, please, edit your question and include this information there with proper as a piece of code for proper indentation.

Comment: @SangeethaNarayanaMoorthy, it really looks that your line do not match your table definition. Or you haven't told us the whole story.

Comment: in csv file , some lines will have null datas .. like that 
first line "AD AD100   Canillo  42.5833    1.6667  6"  does not contains  
state ,  country, country2, community , community2

Comment: @SangeethaNarayanaMoorthy, I see. But there should be `tab` characters between non-existing fields nevertheless. I don't see them. Could post here an example of your input file with literal `\t` (i.e. `\` followed by a `t`) for tabs and `\N` (also 2 chars) for nulls, please?

Comment: @SangeethaNarayanaMoorthy, I cannot test, 'cos all tabs are converted to spaces.

Comment: @SangeethaNarayanaMoorthy, Could post here an example of your input file with literal `\t` (i.e. `\ ` followed by a `t`) for tabs and \N (also 2 chars) for nulls, please?